# Reference HttpSessionListener instance without using a singleton or static

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I've registered an `HttpSessionListener` in my `web.xml` and it is working fine, however I need to access the object instance from other areas (for example Servlets) and would prefer to not use the old `public static HttpSessionListener obj = this;` (pseudo) pattern.

Is there a way to gain access to this object via the J2ee API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to access a session listener from a servlet.

It sounds like what you really want to do is refactor an object from the session listener, and access it via `ServletContext`. Then it will be accessible from both the servlet and the listener.

See the [J2EE Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Servlets5.html#wp66698) for more information about scoped attributes.

Comment: so to clarify, you're suggesting I create an object as an attribute of the `ServletContext` and manage it from within the `HttpSessionListener` ? that would work ..

Comment: @pstanton: That's what the suggestion sounds like. Regardless of where you store it for access, it definitely sounds like you need to extract the common functionality to a shared object.

Comment: @pstanton - yes, that's what I'm saying. The real question is "why does the servlet care about the session listener?" The only reason that I can think of is that you have a monitoring servlet, perhaps to keep track of the number of active sessions. In that case, the data is what you should share, and it can be shared via the application context. If your use case is different, please elaborate.

Comment: @parsifal your answer is somewhat misleading since it talkes about "application context" but does not mention `ServletContext`. A good answer on SO leaves nothing to interpretation.

Comment: @pstanton - my apologies, I mistyped "context" when I meant to type "scope." The term "application scope" is familiar to JSP programmers as a parameter to `jsp:useBean`, although it seems that the official tutorial (which I linked above) is now calling it "web context."